# In Matlab Simulink Block Fliping

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have been trying to flip the (IGBT with Diode) block vertically with the gate facing downwards but the ctrl+R command is not doing it.

Comment: Try various combinations with `Ctrl+R` and `Ctrl+I`

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the gate and collector terminals facing downwards, and emitter facing up? If so, then did you try rotating it several times until this orientation was obtained?